# ValueError: Error retrieving component unknown: The component has not been constructed

Tags: python, spyder

ValueError: Error retrieving component unknown: The component has not been constructed.

I am unsure how to solve this any help is much appreciated. I have added my data file as well if that is the issue. thank you agian for the support [image]

[image]